# How do I use the gimp print plugin dialog instead of the windows 11 print dialog in gimp 2.10?

Tags: printing, images, gimp

I want to set DPI and see what else gimp has to offer for printing images as sharp as possible. But after installing gimp 2.10.34 under Windows 11, it just opens the Windows default printing dialog (which just offers a few print sizes), instead of gimp's own.

The gimp plugin browser already shows the "Print" plugin. No indication whether it is installed or enabled, though, so I assume it is.

How can I switch from system print dialog to gimp's?

I did a fresh gimp install and just disabled Translations but apart form that left all check boxes enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using the command from this site: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-legacy-print-dialog-windows-11/

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Print\UnifiedPrintDialog" /v "PreferLegacyPrintDialog" /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f`

Though this affects all other applications, I think the old dialog was better anyway.